# Want RegionPlot with cut-outs for complex branch cuts

Tags: plotting, complex

```
RegionPlot[Abs@Arg[x+I y]<Pi,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
Plot3D[Abs@Arg[x+I y],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
ContourPlot[Abs@Arg[x+I y]<Pi,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

I was expecting to see a cut-out for the negative x (real) axis in the
RegionPlot. It shows just fine in the Plot3D. The documentation page for
RegionPlot says that it can only plot 2dim areas, not 1dim areas, and if
one wants to see 1dim areas, one should use ContourPlot. OK, fine, but
then with CoutourPlot I don't see it either. Not excluding them simply
shows a wrong rectangle! The negative x-axis should *not* be part of the
plotted rectangle!

Comment: "RegionPlot" is a numerical routine. I samples the available space and you can no expect it to find a feature with a measure of zero. Further,  "ContourPlot" takes a function or an equation as argument, therefore, you must say: `ContourPlot[Abs[Arg[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: And when you do `ContourPlot[Abs[Arg[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`, there *is* a branch cut along the negative real axis (at least in the version I'm using).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Yes, the "<Pi" was wrong, now it works well with a ContourPlot.